# How to add checksum in the log backup script?

Tags: sql-server

I have a mssql script which I want to use for daily full and log backups, I am not able to understand how to add CHECKSUM value to get this to work, can anyone help me around this:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name   
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files   
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup   
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name  

SET @path = 'C:\Backup\'   

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112)  
   + '_'  
   + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),108),':','') 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT name  
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases  
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  
   AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(name, 'Recovery') IN ('FULL','BULK_LOGGED') 

OPEN db_cursor    
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name    

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
BEGIN    
       SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.TRN'   
       BACKUP LOG @name TO DISK = @fileName   

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name    
END    

CLOSE db_cursor    
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: a `checksum` of what, exactly?  And for what purpose?

Comment: What makes you think you need to use CHECKSUM?   Are you following a tutorial or article you read?   What is the link?

Comment: We need DMS Online migration utility which needs to have checksum enabled on all of the backups.

Answer (score 1):

Your command should look like this:

```
BACKUP LOG @name TO DISK = @fileName with checksum
```

You can find this syntax here [Enable or Disable Backup Checksums During Backup or Restore (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/enable-or-disable-backup-checksums-during-backup-or-restore-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and here [BACKUP (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) under 
*Error Management Options*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're really asking for is a [RESTORE VERIFYONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-verifyonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which will check the state of the backup file that was created.

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = @fileName;
```